# Boundary of a set in metric space

Tags: calculus, general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm trying to find the boundary of a set in order to check whether or not the set is open or closed on the metric I'm given. While I understand the latter, I'm not sure how to properly understand the former. The set is given by $$M=\left\{\vec v = \begin{pmatrix}v_1 \\v_2  \\\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ \middle|\  -1 \leq v_1 < 1 \right\}. $$ Am I right in assuming that my set is only bounded to the left and right by $[-1,1)$ and approaches infinity when going "upward" and "downward"? How would I describe the boundaries, then? Thanks for any help or tips.

Comment: That is the picture, yes.  The boundary is therefore the two vertical lines $\{\pm 1\}\times\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I have just edited my post since I originally had falsely posted that $-1 \leq v_1 \leq 1$. How could I describe my boundry now, since I can't take $1 \cdot \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The boundary is still $\{\pm 1\}\times\mathbb{R}$.  It is the set of points of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is "approachable" from $M$ and also from $M^c$.

Comment: So my set is both open and closed?

Comment: No, your set is neither open nor closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, the set is a vertical band in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  The picture looks like this:

[image]

The boundary of a set consists of all of the points that are "close to" the set and also "close to" the complement of the set, where "close to" is a term that I will make rigorous below.  From the picture, it appears that the boundary consists of two vertical lines:  $\{x=-1\}$ and $\{x=1\}$.

Now, to make it rigorous:

> **Definition:** Let $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ (or, more generally, let $E$ be a subset of a metric space).  A point $x$ is a *boundary point* of $E$ if for any $\varepsilon > 0$, we have
>   $$ B(x,\varepsilon) \cap E \ne \varnothing
> \qquad\text{and}\qquad
> B(x,\varepsilon) \cap E^\complement \ne \varnothing.$$

In other words, a point is a boundary point if every ball around that point intersects both the set itself, and the complement (that is, all of the points in the boundary are close to both the set and its complement).  In the case of the set $M$ which you define, any ball around a point of the form $(\pm 1, y)$ contains some point in the set, and some point outside of the set, e.g., assuming that $\varepsilon < 2$,
$$ \left(1-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}, 0\right) \in B(1,0) \cap M,
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\left(1+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}, 0\right) \in B(1,0) \cap M^\complement. $$

On the other hand, if you take any other point $x$ in the plane, then we can find a $\varepsilon > 0$ so small that the ball of radius $\varepsilon$ centered at that point is either completely in $M$ (if $x\in M$), or in the complement of $M$ (if $x\in M^\complement$).

---

This set is neither open nor closed.  To make sense of this, we require a definition of what it means for a set to be open or closed.  There are many equivalent definitions; I'm going to go with the following:

> **Definition:** A set $U$ is *open* if for any $x\in U$ there exists some $r > 0$ such that $B(x,r) \subseteq U$.  A set $K$ is *closed* if it is the complement of an open set.

In the case of $M$, above, it is not open.  To see this, note that $(-1,0)$ is in $M$, but no ball around this point is completely contained in $M$ (this was noted above).  On the other hand, $M^\complement$ is not open either, since no ball around $(1,0)$ is completely contained in $M^\complement$.

This, by the way, suggests another notion of "closed":

> **Definition:** A set is *closed* if it contains all of its boundary points.  A set is *open* if it is the complement of a closed set.

Hence we can determine the openess or closedness of a set by examining its boundary, which is likely what this exercise was intended to get at in the first place. ;)

Comment: Thanks so much for your great and very helpful answer. But could you explain why we take $\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1-\epsilon}{2} \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1+\epsilon}{2} \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @M.P. The point $p = (1,0)$ is in the complement of $M$ (it is on the vertical line on the right side of the strip).  To show that this point is in the boundary, wsince the have to show that any ball centered at the point contains at least one point in $M$, and at least one point in $M^{\complement}$.  The points $(1-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}, 0)$ is a point in $M$ (since the $x$-coordinate is less than 1), and the point $(1+\frac{\varepsilon}{2},0)$ is in the complement.  Though, to be fair, the first statement is only true if $\varepsilon < 2$, but this is dealt with easily enough).

Comment: Thanks, again, for that really comprehensive answer, but I just noticed and maybe should have added that I'm required to show whether the set is open or closed on the metric $d(\vec u, \vec v) = 2|u_1-v_1|+3|u_2-v_2|$.

Comment: @M.P. At this point, since you left that out of your original question, it might be wise to ask a new question with *that* metric in mind.  However, that metric just "stretches" the usual metric, and should have all of the same topological properties.  If you understand what is happening in the usual metric, you should be able to figure it out for this weird metric.  You might also consider drawing some balls in the funny metric---it might give you some insight.

Comment: The fact I had to change the metric actually gave me a lot of time to think about your great post which was really good. For the example you gave, since my ball now looks like a cube which on the x-axis goes from (-0.5,0.5), I think I only let $(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, 0) \in B(1,0) \cap M$ and $(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, 0) \in B(1,0) \cap M^C$ be for $\varepsilon <1$ and it should still apply, right. The rest, as far as I understood, doesn't change anyway. Thanks again for the awesome help you provided yesterday.